# How to add Link in Draft-JS (no plugins)

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I'm trying to create a button which onClick will give you an option to put link, then this link has to be displayed as  tag in the text field. So far I manage to add and display the plain text but I don't know how to transfrom it to an  tag.

```
// Link function
  const addLinkFn = (editorState, link) => {
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
      "LINK",
      "IMMUTABLE",
      { url: link }
    );
    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, {
      currentContent: contentStateWithEntity,
    });
    return AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(newEditorState, entityKey, link);
  };

  const onAddLink = () => {
    let link = window.prompt("Add link http:// ");
    const newEditorState = addLinkFn(editorState, link);
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
  };
```

I know that somewhere I must have a "decorator" and "strategy" like this:

```
const linkStrategy = (contentBlock, callback, contentState) => {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges((character) => {
    const entityKey = character.getEntity();
    return (
      entityKey !== null &&
      contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === "LINK"
    );
  }, callback);
};

const Link = (props) => {
  const { contentState, entityKey } = props;
  const { url } = contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getData();
  return (
    <a
      className="link"
      href={url}
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
      target="_blank"
      aria-label={url}
    >
      {props.children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

and then declare them like this:

```
decorators: [
    {
      strategy: linkStrategy,
      component: Link,
    },
  ],
```

Just I'm not sure how to put everything together to make it works :D
Thank you !

Comment: I think you didn't search well, but anyway check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-link-example-filks

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out.
The whole component looks like this:

```
//Add Link Component
import React from "react";
import { CompositeDecorator, EditorState, Modifier } from "draft-js";

const Link = ({ entityKey, contentState, children }) => {
    let { url } = contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getData();
    return (
        <a
            style={{ color: "blue", fontStyle: "italic" }}
            href={url}
            target="_blank"
        >
            {children}
        </a>
    );
};

const findLinkEntities = (contentBlock, callback, contentState) => {
    contentBlock.findEntityRanges((character) => {
        const entityKey = character.getEntity();
        return (
            entityKey !== null &&
            contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === "LINK"
        );
    }, callback);
};

export const createLinkDecorator = () =>
    new 
        CompositeDecorator
([
    {
        strategy: findLinkEntities,
        component: Link,
    },
]);

// call all together
export const onAddLink = (editorState, setEditorState) => {
    let linkUrl = window.prompt("Add link http:// ");
    const decorator = createLinkDecorator();
    if (linkUrl) {
        let displayLink = window.prompt("Display Text");
        if (displayLink) {
            const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
            const createEntity = currentContent.createEntity("LINK", "MUTABLE", {
                url: linkUrl,
            });
            let entityKey = currentContent.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
            const selection = editorState.getSelection();
            const textWithEntity = Modifier.insertText(
                currentContent,
                selection,
                displayLink,
                null,
                entityKey
            );
            let newState = EditorState.createWithContent(textWithEntity, decorator);
            setEditorState(newState);
        }
    }
};
```

Then you have to attach it to the editor toolbar (if you have one:

```js
import { onAddLink } from "./Link";  
<button
    onClick={() => onAddLink(props.editorState, props.setEditorState)}
>
    link
</button>
```

Then refer the deocrator in the display part of the editor so it knows how the link looks like:

```js
import { createLinkDecorator } from "./Components/Link"; 
const decorator = createLinkDecorator();
const editorState = props.postData
    ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(props.postData), 
        // add the decorator after the state
        decorator
    )
    : EditorState.createEmpty();
```